# Could I say one of these phrases?

Tags: phrase-meaning

Could I say one of the phrases below?

"The valedictorians of the last 5 years..."

or

"The last 5 years valedictorians..."

instead of saying "In the last 5 years, the valedictorians..."

Comment: The first is okay. The second (even with an apostrophe **years'**) is not idiomatic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "The last 5 years' valedictorians." is better (with the apostrophe) , but both ok. Less is more.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to ELL. Please take the [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour) and consider how you might [improve your answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). As it stands, this sounds like opinion; can you quote and link to sources that support your position?